# Append item to string in TCL

Tags: tcl

Suppose I have a variable as such

```
set var {H}
```

How can I do something like this

```
var = var + "ello";
```

the output of the above would be Hello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use append:

```
append var "ello"
```